# Javascript/CSS/HTML/Java IDE?

Tags: java, javascript, c++, netbeans, aptana

So here we go. I want to choose between Aptana, Eclipse, and Netbeans. I want a sort of all inclusive program as I try out these different languages to see what I want to try out. I have VS for my C/C++. So do any of these support HTML, CSS, Javascript, and Java? I think it's netbeans but I'm not sure.

Also, what is the best paid app for Javascript? Is dreamweaver any good?

Comment: Try them all out and see for yourself (it's the only way).

Comment: i use netbeans for php/javascript/css/html. eclipse is about the same. it's whatever you're used to, just pick one and configure it properly. dreamweaver is also good (at least for what i've heard). there is no "best" IDE

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Aptana, Eclipse, and Netbeans all support HTML, CSS, JavaScript and Java.

Aptana is actually Eclipse under the covers with what looks like better support for web applications.

I have used Eclipse extensively and found that it was sufficient for my Java web development work.

Recently I have switched to using [IntelliJ IDEA](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/) after using their JavaScript IDE - [Webstorm](http://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/). IntelliJ IDEA is a full-featured IDE with great support for various languages and frameworks. Webstorm (as far as I can tell) is a cut-down version of IntelliJ IDEA specifically focused on JavaScript development.

The great thing about IntelliJ IDEA and Webstorm is their support for mixed languages. That is, if you have HTML, CSS, and Javascript all in one file, it understands it all and highlights, and formats, the code for you properly. Another great feature are the code inspections which analyse your code for errors and common mistakes - this is a great feature.

Both IntelliJ IDEA and Webstorm are paid applications, but you can try them out for free for 30 days.

I would highly recommend trying out IntelliJ IDEA and/or Webstorm.

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse is a develpoers best friend. Every language leave for .NET, but it's MEANT for Java, and the others. And NEVER buy an app to develop, it becomes a crutch.

And Eclipse has a million and a half plug-ins that can become super useful... just found this LESS CSS compiler that runs on file save... epic!

Comment: the best paid app for javascript is Eclipse ... :), i would recommend Eclipse too

Comment: Yeah but if i want support for Java too, shouldn't i just get netbeans?

Comment: No, seriously, once you use eclipse you'll never go back bro... it was MADE for Java... go to the website, you'll s**t that you don't already use it.

Comment: does it run  javascript and java?

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what you're doing but every place I've worked for prefers Eclipse over anything else, may just be industry standard but I get along with Eclipse very well. One thing that stands out it's modularity and the ability to find a plugin for any specific technology. I have used Netbeans in the past and it's not bad - perhaps the biggest advantage, at least when I was using it, was the built-in GUI builder specific to Swing applications but I suppose it's a matter of preference in the end. I believe both have support for the technologies that you mentioned although I haven't encountered Aptana before.

Answer (score 0):

Aptana is actually Eclipse, bundled directly with highlighters for CSS, HTML, JS and adds additional very handy functionality. But you just as well could use eclipse and download all the plugins via the plugin manager and you'd have the experience of pornific-java developement, as well as porntastic javascript/html/css possibilities.

I'd recommend Aptana, unless you really need Java, then I'd do the Eclipse+Plugins attempt.

Answer (score 0):

There are Eclipse builds for everything and is widely used. Netbeans is more for (you guessed it) web development, but I find a lot of people find it easier to use. Eclipse confuses people when they start using it. They both do HTML, JavaScript and CSS pretty well.

Comment: Yes they both do Java and c++. You can see all difference builds of eclipse [here](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/) including one for c/c++. [Netbeans](http://netbeans.org/index.html) apparently also does c/c++